# What are the conditions for $\arctan x+\arctan y+\arctan z=\arctan\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$ to be true?

Tags: trigonometry

This is the formula:

$$\arctan x+\arctan y+\arctan z=\arctan\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$$

Should the condition be $|xy+yz+zx|<1$?

Related: [Why does the equation with $2 \arctan(x)$ and other Inverse Trigonometric functions have weird conditions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3803025/768162)

Comment: Nope, the condition is $1 > xy+yz+zx$. Nothing special happens at $xy+yz+xz = -1$

Comment: Arctangents are between $-\pi/2$ and $+\pi/2,$ or $-90^\circ$ and $+90^\circ$ if you like. But the sum of arctangents may be more than $+\pi/2$ or less than $-\pi/2. \qquad$

Comment: @achillehui : How did you reach your conclsion?

Comment: @achillehui ; If your statement is right, then $|a+b+c|>\pi/2$ is the same as $\tan a\tan b + \tan a\tan c + \tan b\tan c>1. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy LHS - RHS is  a constant as long as $xy+yz+xz \ne 1$. This separate $\mathbb{R}^3$ into 3 regions, you pick a point from each region and figure out the constant. This is essentially the argument I gave in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027564/59379)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y+\tan^{-1}z=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$ true for all $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027479/tan-1x-tan-1y-tan-1z-tan-1-fracxyz-xyz1-xy-yz-zx-true-fo)

Comment: @achillehui Isn't |xy+yz+zx|<1 and xy+yz+zx<1 the same thing?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Not really  LHS = RHS for $xy+yz+xz < -1$. eg. pick $(x,y,z) = (2t,-t,-t)$ for some large $t$, even though the magnitude of all arctan in LHS are big (close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$), their 'sign' force the sum to fall within $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and equal to RHS.

Comment: @achillehui Hmmm. Aside from trigonometry though, in simple algebra, isn't |xy+yz+zx|<1 and xy+yz+zx<1 the same thing kind sir?

Comment: $|u|<1$ means $-1 < u < 1$. in this case $xy+yz+zx$ can be as negative as one wish.

Comment: @achillehui Oh I understand it now. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just $xy+yz+zx<1$. If $xy+yz+zx>1$, $\pi$ or $-\pi$ needs to be added to the RHS. A possible approach to see this. For the [sum of two arctangents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326334/a-question-about-the-arctangent-addition-formula), we have
$$\arctan u+\arctan v=\begin{cases}
\arctan\frac{u+v}{1-uv}, & uv<1\\
\pi+\arctan\frac{u+v}{1-uv}, & uv>1\text{ and } u,v>0\\
-\pi+\arctan\frac{u+v}{1-uv}, & uv>1\text{ and } u,v<0\\
\pi/2, & uv=1\text{ and } u,v>0\\
-\pi/2, & uv=1\text{ and } u,v<0\\
\end{cases} $$
Apply this twice: first with $u=x,v=y$, then with $u=(x+y)/(1-xy),v=z$ and consider the various cases for the products $xy$ and $z(x+y)/(1-xy)$ with possible subcases for the signs of $x,y,z$ (yes, that's a lot of cases). For example, when
$xy<1$ and $\frac{z(x+y)}{1-xy}<1\Rightarrow xy+yz+zx<1$, we have
$$\arctan x+\arctan y+\arctan z=\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}+\arctan{z}=\arctan\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$$
In the case $xy>1$ and $\frac{z(x+y)}{1-xy}>1\Rightarrow xy+yz+zx<1$ with $x,y>0$ and $z<0$, we have
$$\arctan x+\arctan y+\arctan z=\pi+\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}+\arctan{z}\\
=\pi+(-\pi)+\arctan\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}=\arctan\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$$
And continue with the other cases. If you want to avoid this laborious case checking, consider achille hui's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027564/570684) which uses geometrical reasoning about the region $xy+yz+zx\ne 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer kind sir. I had another question: isn't |xy+yz+zx|<1 and xy+yz+zx<1 the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

It is sufficient that the sum of the three arctangents is between $\pm\pi/2.$

For $x,y,z\in\mathbb R,$ the value of $$\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-xz-yz}\in\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$$ is always equal to $$\tan(\arctan x + \arctan y + \arctan z)\in\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}, $$ since $$\tan(\arctan x) = x \text{ for every } x\in\mathbb R$$
and for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R,$
$$
\tan(a+b+c) = \frac{\tan a+\tan b+\tan c-\tan a\tan b\tan c}{1 - \tan a\tan b - \tan a \tan c - \tan b\tan c} \in\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}.
$$
(This $\text{“}\infty\text{”}$ is neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty,$ but is approached by going in either the positive or the negative direction, so $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ is topologically a circle.)

However, in some cases $\arctan (\tan a) \ne a,$ namely in those cases in which $a\notin(-\pi/2,+\pi/2).$