# Is this trigonometric inequality widely known?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

The conjunction of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027479/tan-1x-tan-1y-tan-1z-tan-1-fracxyz-xyz1-xy-yz-zx-true-fo/3027564#3027564) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336163/what-are-the-conditions-for-arctan-x-arctan-y-arctan-z-arctan-fracxyz-xy/4336614#4336614) would seem to imply that for $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3 \in(-\pi/2,+\pi/2),$
$$
|\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3| < \frac \pi 2 \text{ if and only if } \tan\theta_1\tan\theta_2 + \tan\theta_1\tan\theta_3 + \tan\theta_2\tan\theta_3<1. \tag 1
$$
And a bit of number crunching and graphing via software seems to suggest that maybe
$$
\sup\big\{ \arctan( \tan\theta_1\tan\theta_2 + \tan\theta_1\tan\theta_3 + \tan\theta_2\tan\theta_3 ) : \theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3=s \big\} \\[8pt] = \frac\pi4(1-\cos s) \text{ if $|s|<\pi/2$ ??} \tag 2
$$
or some function similar to that. And if $|s|>\pi/2,$ put $\inf$ there instead of $\sup.$

The equality in $(2)$ seems far-fetched, and concerning $(1)$ I wonder if there's an efficient way of showing it, as opposed to juxtaposing the two answers I linked. If the hour were not late, I would figure this all out myself, except for the answer to this question: Is this stuff known?

Comment: You'd need the additional restriction $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Then this'd follow from the correctness of the identity for the sum of 3 arctangents.

Comment: @bjorn93 : Note that I said "efficient". Quite likely I'll post my own answer later, after I've looked at the details and polished it to be slick and simple.